# SSLSocketFactory using pre-install CAs

Tags: java, security, ssl, tls1.2

I have created a SSLSocketFactory that load TrustManagerFactory given the trust store as shown below. I will like to know in there is a way to create a SSL factory that loads all preinstalled certificate (similarly as the browser does). In other words accept all cert that the computer/docker container/JVM already has.
(I'm not security expert, I hope the question is adequate.)

```
/**
 * Provide a quick method to construct a SSLSocketFactory which is a TCP socket using TLS/SSL
 * @param trustStore location of the trust store
 * @param keyStore location of the key store
 * @param trustStorePassword password to access the trust store
 * @param keyStorePassword password to access the key store
 * @return the SSLSocketFactory to create secure sockets with the provided certificates infrastructure
 * @exception java.lang.Exception in case of something wrong happens
 * */
static public SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory ( final String trustStore, final String keyStore, final String trustStorePassword, final String keyStorePassword) throws Exception
{

    // todo check if the CA needs or can use the password
    final FileInputStream trustStoreStream = new FileInputStream(trustStore);
    final FileInputStream keyStoreStream = new FileInputStream(keyStore);
    // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
    final KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    caKs.load(trustStoreStream, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
    final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
    tmf.init(caKs);

    trustStoreStream.close();

    // client key and certificates are sent to server so it can authenticate us
    final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(keyStoreStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
    kmf.init(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

    keyStoreStream.close();

    // finally, create SSL socket factory
    final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return context.getSocketFactory();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which browser(s) on which system(s)? They vary quite a bit, but none of them use a Java truststore as such, although some browsers on some Unixes may use a truststore which has the same _entries_ as the truststore used for OpenJDK but not Oracle/Sun Java. OTOH if you are happy with your Java's default truststore, which is the file (or link) `JRE/lib/security/cacerts` unless configured otherwise or `jssecacerts` exists, just pass null to the second argument of `SSLContext.init`.

Comment: Why don't you answer the question such I eventually give you the credit?